# F-rationality of a ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Given $R = \dfrac{k[x,y,z]}{(x^2 - y^3 -z^5)} $  where $\operatorname{char}k>5$. Check whether $R$ is $F$-rational or not. ($F$ = Frobenius map)

I know, by the theorem of Karen Smith, we have to check that there is no proper non trivial submodule of $H_m^d(R)$ ($d=\dim R$) stable under Frobenius action. But I can't do that explicit calculation. Can anyone help me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that theorem can be very helpful.

Instead, one can use a result of Hochster and Huneke saying that a local ring which is a homomorphic image of a local Cohen-Macaulay ring is $F$-rational iff it is equidimensional and a parameter ideal is tightly closed. (There is also a graded version of this result relying on the $a$-invariant of $R$.)

In our example the ideal $I=(y,z)$ is a parameter ideal, and $R/I\simeq k[x]/(x^2)$. If $I$ were not tightly closed, then $I\subsetneq I^*$ and since the only proper ideal if $R/I$ is generated by $x$ it follows $x\in I^*$. But for $\operatorname{char}k\ge 7$ one can show that $x\notin I^*$ (see Bruns and Herzog, 10.1.3), arriving at a contradiction. Thus $R$ is $F$-rational. (Moreover, since $R$ is Gorenstein it follows that it is $F$-regular.)